# Recuse myself from protecting a question I answered that contains other deleted spam answers?

Tags: discussion, protected-questions

I recently received an upvote on my old answer to [Javadoc link to method in other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496038/javadoc-link-to-method-in-other-class/17496080).  That prompted me to revisit that page.

I discovered that there are 3 deleted spam/offensive answers on this question.  But, the Community user hasn't protected it.  Should I protect this question?  Will it appear bad if I protect a question that I have already answered, on the basis of preventing competing answers?

I would protect the question if I didn't already answer it.  So the key point to consider here is the fact that I already have answered it.  Should I recuse myself based on that fact, and not protect it, or just go ahead and protect it anyway?

Comment: If I believe a question needs protecting, I'd protect... but even if you don't want to, joining a chat room is the second best option.

Comment: It looks like the same person spammed that one post 3 times, and not recently.  I see no compelling evidence that the post itself is attracting non-answers and thus merits protecting.  When one user is just trolling/spamming the solution is to get rid of the troll/spammer.  When a post is attracting non-answers from lots of different people, that's where protection comes in.

Comment: The Stack Overflow threshold for auto-protection is 5 I think (see [Auto-protect questions that get more than N answers from new users in a 24-hour period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228805)). I don't see any reason to protect the post here; it was one troll user (using new accounts) way back in August last year, not a spammer.

Comment: For those who are wondering... http://www.thefreedictionary.com/recuse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *this specific instance* protection would be overkill. The three posts were  created by a persistent troll account, not a spammer, and I don't think the question is particularly at risk of being a spam magnet. The three deleted posts are all along the lines of unicode-laced nonsense, and the troll either gave up or was blocked more effectively at the IP level.

In the general case, I personally would not have any problems with you protecting a question you answered, provided there is evidence that protection was warranted. When in doubt, join a chat room relevant to the site and / or topic and discuss there, I'm sure someone else can do the protecting for you if needed.

Protection is easily undone again, I'm sure that any abusive behaviour would be swiftly dealt with by moderators, and protection doesn't lock out the experienced answerers, which usually are the more likely competition to answer questions better than you do. :-)

Comment: Ok, I won't protect that question, but I will protect another question that needs it, even if I've answered it, and the Community user or another user hasn't already protected it.  Thanks.